# Skeleton Example for Swift Combine Publisher-Subscriber

Tags: swift, publish-subscribe, swift5, combine

As I port some Objective-C code to Swift, I'm trying to better understand the new `Combine` framework and how I can use it to re-create a common design pattern.

In this case, the design pattern is a single object (Manager, Service, etc) that any number of "clients" can register with as a delegate to receive callbacks. It's a basic 1:Many pattern using delegates.

`Combine` looks ideal for this, but the sample code is a bit thin. Below is a working example but I'm not sure if it's correct or being used as intended. In particular, I'm curious about reference cycles between the objects.

```
class Service {

  let tweets = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

  func start() {
    // Simulate the need send to send updates.
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
      while true {
        self.sendTweet()
        usleep(100000)
      }
    }
  }

  func sendTweet() {
    tweets.send("Message \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)")
  }
}

class Client : Subscriber {
  typealias Input = String
  typealias Failure = Never

  let service:Service
  var subscription:Subscription?

  init(service:Service) {
    self.service = service

   // Is this a retain cycle?
   // Is this thread-safe? 
    self.service.tweets.subscribe(self) 
  }

  func receive(subscription: Subscription) {
    print("Received subscription: \(subscription)")

    self.subscription = subscription
    self.subscription?.request(.unlimited)
  }

  func receive(_ input: String) -> Subscribers.Demand {
    print("Received tweet: \(input)")
    return .unlimited
  }

  func receive(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Never>) {
    print("Received completion")
  }
}

// Dependency injection is used a lot throughout the 
// application in a similar fashion to this:

let service = Service()
let client = Client(service:service)

// In the real world, the service is started when
// the application is launched and clients come-and-go.

service.start()
```

---

Output is:

```
Received subscription: PassthroughSubject
Received tweet: Message 1560371698.300811
Received tweet: Message 1560371698.4087949
Received tweet: Message 1560371698.578027
...
```

Is this even remotely close to how `Combine` was intended to be used?

Comment: "I'm curious about reference cycles between the objects" why you don't open instruments and find out?

Comment: With little documentation or sample code to go on, I was looking for confirmation or correction as to whether this is a correct interpretation of how Publishers and Subscribers should interact. While it works, it might not be "correct", which is what I was attempting to ask.

Comment: Refer: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/custom-combine-publisher/

Answer (score 3):

lets check it! the simplest way is add deinit to both classes and limit the live of service

```
class Service {
    
    let tweets = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    
    func start() {
        // Simulate the need send to send updates.
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
            (0 ... 3).forEach { _ in
                self.sendTweet()
                usleep(100000)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func sendTweet() {
        tweets.send("Message \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)")
    }
    deinit {
        print("server deinit")
    }
}
```

now it is easy to check that

```
do {
    let service = Service()
    //_ = Client(service:service)
    
    // In the real world, the service is started when
    // the application is launched and clients come-and-go.
    
    service.start()
}
```

will finished as expected

```
server deinit
```

modify it with subscribing client

```
do {
    let service = Service()
    _ = Client(service:service)
    service.start()
}
```

and you immediately know the result

```
Received subscription: PassthroughSubject
Received tweet: Message 1580816649.7355099
Received tweet: Message 1580816649.8548698
Received tweet: Message 1580816650.001649
Received tweet: Message 1580816650.102639
```

there is a memory cycle, as you expected :-)

Generally, there is very low probability, that you need your own subscriber implementation.

First modify the service, so the client will know when no more messages will arrive

```
func start() {
        // Simulate the need send to send updates.
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
            // send some tweets
            (0 ... 3).forEach { _ in
                self.sendTweet()
                usleep(100000)
            }
            // and send "finished"
            self.tweets.send(completion: .finished)
        }
    }
```

and next use "build-in" subcriber in your publisher by invoking his .sink method. .sink return AnyCancelable (it is a reference type) which you have to store somewhere.

```
var cancelable: AnyCancellable?
do {
    let service = Service()
    service.start()
    
    // client
    cancelable = service.tweets.sink { (s) in
        print(s)
    }
}
```

now, everythig works, es expected ...

```
Message 1580818277.2908669
Message 1580818277.4674711
Message 1580818277.641886
server deinit
```

But what about cancelable? Let check it!

```
var cancelable: AnyCancellable?
do {
    let service = Service()
    service.start()
    
    // client
    cancelable = service.tweets.sink { (s) in
        print(s)
    }
}
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
    print(cancelable)
}
```

it prints

```
Message 1580819227.5750608
Message 1580819227.763901
Message 1580819227.9366078
Message 1580819228.072041
server deinit
Optional(Combine.AnyCancellable)
```

so you have to release it "manualy", if you don't need it anymore. .sink is there again!

```
var cancelable: AnyCancellable?
do {
    let service = Service()
    service.start()
    
    // client
    cancelable = service.tweets.sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
        print(completion)
        // this inform publisher to "unsubscribe" (not necessery in this scenario)
        cancelable?.cancel()
        // and we can release our canceleble
        cancelable = nil
    }, receiveValue: { (message) in
        print(message)
    })
}
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
    print(cancelable)
}
```

and result

```
Message 1580819683.462331
Message 1580819683.638145
Message 1580819683.74383
finished
server deinit
nil
```

Combine has almost everything you need in real word application, the trouble is a lack of documentation, but a lot of sources are available on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Custom Combine Subscriber should also conform to Cancellable protocol that provides a method to forward cancellation to the received subscription object from Publisher. That way you do not have to expose Subscription property. According to doc:

> If you create a custom Subscriber, the publisher sends a Subscription object when you first subscribe to it. Store this subscription, and then call its cancel() method when you want to cancel publishing. When you create a custom subscriber, you should implement the Cancellable protocol, and have your cancel() implementation forward the call to the stored subscription.
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/receiving_and_handling_events_with_combine